# show x axis dates every 6 months

Tags: python, date, matplotlib

```
fig_2 = plt.figure(figsize=(16,6))

axes2 = fig_2.add_axes([0,0,1,1])

axes2.plot(tesla_df['Volume'])
axes2.plot(gm_df['Volume'])
axes2.plot(ford_df['Volume'])

plt.legend(['Tesla','GM','Ford'])

axes2.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.MonthLocator())
axes2.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%m--%Y'))
```

How can I make the dates on my chart appear every 6 months on the x axis instead of every month?

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 4):

You would specify the months to tick in the initialization of the `MonthLocator`. So for the months January and July

```
matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator((1,7))
```

If you don't care about which months to tick, you can also specify the interval

```
matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator(interval=6)
```